# Props is not defined React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm preparing an e-commerce page with React.js. I used Mock Api as api service. I successfully pulled the data, but when I tried to add the product to the cart, I encountered a "props" error.

My function for adding the product to the cart:

```
handleClick() {
        props.dispatch(addProductToCart({...this.props.product}))
    }
```

This is the part where I return the button in my Product.js folder:

Product.js is written using class component.

```
return(
<div>
<button onClick= {this.handleClick}>
        Add to cart
    </button>
</div>
)
```

I called this function in my ProductDetail.js file like this:

```
const onCart = () => {
        props.dispatch(addProductToCart(this.props.product));
    };
```

The Error Output :

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/Product/Product.js
Line 19: 'props' is not defined no-undef
Line 20:  'props' is not defined no-undef
```

It seems that the prop `addProductToCart` cannot be read when it is inside the `onCart` method and I'm not sure what is causing this

Comment: Looks like you're using `props` and `this.props` - which one is correct?

Comment: are you passing props as an argument to the component?

Comment: for class-based components, you have to access `props` through `this` keyword. As for functional components, you can access it as the first params of your function. From the look of your handleClick, it's should be `this.props.dispatch(...)`.